# How to transfer an image from a client to a database using a FLASK API REST server

Tags: python, database, flask

I'm trying to save an image to a database using the FLASK REST API. After extensive research, I have found that the best way to do this is to create a folder on the server that will contain the image file or other files and this is the path to each file that is stored in the database. In my database, the "Fichiers" table has four columns including a foreign key. To carry out my requests, I use the requests module on the client side. The difficulty I'm having is transferring the image and the foreign key at the same time. I want to insert my foreign key directly into the url, but I don't think that's a good method.

this is my client code:

```html
from plyer import filechooser
import os
import requests

def selected(selection):
    try:
        source = selection[0]
        nom_image = os.path.basename(source)
        url = 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/upload'
        files = {'image': (nom_image, open(source, 'rb'))}
        data = {'fk_id': 1}
        response = requests.post(url, files=files, json=data)

        if response.status_code == 200:
            print('Fichier envoyé avec succès.')
        else:
            print(f"Erreur lors de l'envoi du fichier : {response.text}")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Erreur : {str(e)}")

filechooser.open_file(on_selection=selected)
```

This my server code using FLASK:

```html
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify, send_file
import os 
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename
import sqlite3


app = Flask(__name__)

#Répertoire où stocker les images et fichiers sur le serveur
UPLOAD_FOLDER = 'uploads'
app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = UPLOAD_FOLDER

#Vérifier si le repertoire d'upload exist, sinon, le créer

if not os.path.exists(UPLOAD_FOLDER):
    os.makedirs(UPLOAD_FOLDER)

@app.route('/upload', methods = ['POST'])
def upload_file():
    try:
        #récupérer le fichier depuis la requete du client
        uploaded_file = request.files['image']
        idd = request.files['id']
        print(idd)
        print(uploaded_file)

        data = request.json
        fk_id = data.get('fk_id')

        #Sécuriser le nom du fichier pour éviter des problemes de sécurité
        filename = secure_filename(uploaded_file.filename)

        #Enregistrer le fichier dans le répertoire spécifié sur le serveur
        file_path = os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename)
        uploaded_file.save(file_path)

        #Enregistrer dans la base de donnée
        conn = sqlite3.connect('mabase.sqlite3')
        cur = conn.cursor()
        req = "INSERT INTO Image (nom, lien, fk_id) VALUES(?, ?, ?)"
        valeur = (uploaded_file.filename, file_path, fk_id)
        cur.execute(req, valeur)
        conn.commit()

        return jsonify({'message': 'File uploaded successfully', 'file_path': file_path}), 200
    except Exception as e:
        return jsonify({'error': f'Error uploading file: {str(e)}'}), 500
```

this is the error I get on the client side when I add another json parameter to the requsest function:
Erreur lors de l'envoi du fichier : {
"error": "Error uploading file: 400 Bad Request: The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand."
}

This is the error I get on server side:
127.0.0.1 - - [14/Mar/2024 10:36:26] "POST /upload HTTP/1.1" 500 -

please help me with the right method